# liquibase "changelog file classpath name"

Tags: liquibase

In the liquibase [changeSet documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html) it is stated:

> Each changeSet tag is uniquely identified by the combination of the “id” tag, the “author” tag, and the **changelog file classpath name**

Many times I want to avoid identifying a changeSet by its file location and so I use the logicalFilePath in the root element.
Nevertheless I want to better understand how the file-path thing has been designed. 
My question is: what is the difference between simple "file path" and "file class path name"?
I did some testing with a simple changeSet (no logicalFilePath) that creates a simple CUSTOMERS table.

**Run it from c:\projects**

```
C:\projects> liquibase --changeLogFile=.\P1\databaseChangeLog.xml --username=U1 --password=U1 --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe" update
Starting Liquibase at sab, 27 lug 2019 21:55:47 CEST (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
Liquibase: Update has been successful.
```

**Check status from c:\projects**

```
C:\projects> liquibase --changeLogFile=.\P1\databaseChangeLog.xml --username=U1 --password=U1 --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe" status
Starting Liquibase at sab, 27 lug 2019 23:18:06 CEST (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
U1@jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe is up to date
```

As you can see, **it's up to date!**

**Run it from c:\projects\P1**

Here I moved into C:\projects\P1 and so chanageLogFile parameter becomes just the file name: ".\databaseChangeLog.xml" while before it was ".\P1\databaseChangeLog.xml".

```
C:\projects\P1> liquibase --changeLogFile=.\databaseChangeLog.xml --username=U1 --password=U1 --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe" update
Starting Liquibase at sab, 27 lug 2019 21:55:32 CEST (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
 [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE P009T02.CUSTOMERS (ID NUMBER, NAME VARCHAR2(255), SURNAME VARCHAR2(255))]
 ...
```

The changeLogFile has not been changed, but the changeSets are recognized as different because they were identified by their location. (Actually there is just one).
Since it's a different changeset, liquibase tryes to execute it, but since the table already exists it fails.

In the databasechangelog table, in the FILENAME field we have:

```
.\P1\databaseChangeLog.xml
```

This is nothing but what I've specified as the changeLogFile parameter in the first execution.
So, though arguable, the functionin is quite clear; as stated in the documentation it uses the path as key. What remains not so clear is that while it seems to be using the exact string passed as path, documentation talks about this "file classpath" that puzzles me and I would like to know if there is something more to this.

Comment: I guess liquibase can also load the changelog files from the classpath. And that might be why the doc talks about file classpath name. I know not a clear answer. Just my 2 cents....